# Html table width is not proper for diff number of columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I am working with HTML table. I have created a table with 3 rows. First row having
one "key" column and one "value" column. Second row having one "key" column and two "value" column. And third row having one "Key" column and three "value" column. Though 3rd row having 3 column. So I gave first row 1st column "colspan=3" but for 2nd row there are 2 columns so I have to match its width with the 3rd row. But I cant give "colspan=1.5". Even if I give its taking it as round off. I need to match the 1st and 2nd column width with the 1st column.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to create the table which is shown in the following image. I tried with colspan but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: For second column you can take 2 td's one with colspan 1 and second one with colspan 3 and then use 2 divs inside with 50% width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Key</td>
        <td colspan=6>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>key </td>
        <td colspan=3>value</td>
        <td colspan=3>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td colspan=2>value</td>
        <td colspan=2>value</td>
        <td colspan=2>value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to given image you can do using inner HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td colspan="3">Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Value</td>
                <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes its working but I have to write css to remove extra borders If I applied border.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td colspan="6">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td colspan="3">Value</td>
            <td colspan="3">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td>Value</td>
            <td colspan="2">Value</td>
            <td colspan="2">Value</td>
            <td colspan="2">Value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

break it down to even more colspans. basically multiply what you did first with 2.

like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td colspan="6">Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td colspan="3">Value</td>
    <td colspan="3">Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td colspan="2">Value</td>
    <td colspan="2">Value</td>
    <td colspan="2">Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

working fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/t9woe310/3/